# show Latitude and Longitude marker values in iFrame

Tags: javascript, variables, iframe, maps, openlayers

I have a main HTML file (index.html) where i load a Map (OpenLayers) and each time a user click somewhere on the Map a marker is added and a Modal window will open with an iframe inside (iframe_content.html). This iframe content file has a Form with many input fields and i want to show the Latitude and Longitude marker values in the correspondent input field.

I'm a JavaScript noob but at the moment i already can grab those LonLat values and show them on a JS alert, so i guess i only need to figure it out how to "send" these values to the correspondent inputfield located in the other file «iframe_content.html».

Can you please give me some tips on this? Thanks in advance!

NC

[image]

Comment: Map and Modal window loads inside index.html (red color selection), iFrame loads inside the Modal window with an embed file called "iframe_content.html" (blue color selection). I want to show the Lonlat coordinates inside each inputfield with the IDs  marker_lat and marker_lon.

Answer (score 1):

When you load the modal you could have something like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe_id');
var inner  = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

Now if you have the fields as a name array:

```
var fields  = inner.getElementsByName('fields[]');
```

Or get them by the id:

```
var lat_field  = inner.getElementsById('latitude');
var lon_field  = inner.getElementsById('longitude');
```

Now just set the value of the fields to the value you want in this case the coordinates:

```
fields[0].value = coordinate['latitude'];
fields[1].value = coordinate['longitude'];
```

Or with the ids:

```
lat_field.value = coordinate['latitude'];
lon_field.value = coordinate['longitude'];
```